# File found using android MediaStore but BitmapFactory unable to decode it with path returned from MediaStore

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I have searched high and low and not found an answer to my particular question, I hope someone can help.
I am developing this for Android 9 and above, the code I use for older releases works fine.

It's quite simple, I have stored an image in the MediaStore, I have found the image in the media store, I return its path, I check the path exists and it does, it also has a correct size and is visible in the android Gallery. So why when I try to open it with

val bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullPath)

bitmap2 comes back as null - no errors are generated by the above command. The parseAllImages function was taken from the web and tweaked slightly but seems to work ok as far as I can tell.

sample code

```
        private fun setPic() {
        if (mediaPath.isNotEmpty()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                val content = GalleryAdd.parseAllImages(requireActivity(), mediaPath)
                val fullPath = content
                if (File(fullPath).exists()) {
                    val tester = File(fullPath).length()
                    val bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullPath)
                    viewModel.setBitmap(bitmap2)
                }

            }
        }
    }

    fun parseAllImages(act : Activity, name : String) : String {
        try {
            val projection =
                arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
            val cursor = act.contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,  // Which columns to return
                null,  // Return all rows
                null,
                null
            )
            val size: Int = cursor!!.getCount()
            /*******  If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card.  */
            if (size == 0) {
            } else {
                val thumbID = 0
                if (cursor != null) {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        val file_ColumnIndex: Int =
                            cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                        /**************** Captured image details  */
                        /*****  Used to show image on view in LoadImagesFromSDCard class  */
                        val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
                        val path: String = cursor.getString(file_ColumnIndex)
                        val fileName =
                            path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.length)
                        if (fileName == name)
                        {
                            return path
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return ""
    }
```

Code snippet I use to write to the media store

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val resolver: ContentResolver = activity.contentResolver
            val contentValues = ContentValues()
            contentValues.put(
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                fileName
            )
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
            contentValues.put(
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "fishy"
            )
            val imageUri: Uri? =
                resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

            val tester = imageUri.toString() + File.separator +  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "fishy" + File.separator + fileName
            scanLoc = fileName
            fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri!!)!!

        val file = File(currentPhotoPath)
        val ins: InputStream = file.inputStream()
        ins.copyTo(fos)
}
```

Any help or can someone point me to sample code that can read a jpg image from the mediastore given it's name? It's not production ready so please forgive lack of error checks.

Thanks

Lee.

Comment: Use `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` on the content. Pass that to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`.

Comment: Your a star that fixed it, thank you very much.